# How to form two column table in css on Wordpress plugin

Tags: css, wordpress, css-tables

I'm trying to form a table with two columns on a form used by a WordPress plugin. So far I have tried to indent the right hand column using basic indents but the end result ends up where the column on the right isn't exactly vertically inline ( I'm assuming because the text labels are different size). I have tried using a `<td>` type table but everything goes crazy.

I thought to use code like the following but can't seem to figure out where to put it:

```
<style type="text/css">
#wrap {
   width:600px;
   margin:0 auto;
}
#left_col {
   float:left;
   width:300px;

}
#right_col {
   float:right;
   width:300px;
}
</style>

<div id="wrap">
    <div id="left_col">
        ...
    </div>
    <div id="right_col">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

The code I'm using for my form is as follows:

```
<?php
/*
If you would like to edit this file, copy it to your current theme's directory and edit it there.
Theme My Login will always look in your theme's directory first, before using this default template.
*/
?>
<div class="login" id="theme-my-login<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>">
    <?php $template->the_action_template_message( 'register' ); ?>
    <?php $template->the_errors(); ?>
    <form name="registerform" id="registerform<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" action="<?php $template->the_action_url( 'register' ); ?>" method="post">

                <p style="float:left; padding-right:10px;"><label for="user_firstname<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>"><?php _e( 'First Name:', 'theme-my-login' ) ?></label></p>
                <p></p><input type="text" name="user_firstname" id="user_firstname<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" class="input" value="<?php $template->the_posted_value( 'user_firstname' ); ?>" size="20" /></p>


                <p style="float:left; padding-right:10px;"><label for="user_lastname<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>"><?php _e( 'Last Name:', 'theme-my-login' ) ?></label></p>
                <p></p><input type="text" name="user_lastname" id="user_lastname<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" class="input" value="<?php $template->the_posted_value( 'user_lastname' ); ?>" size="20" /></p>


                <p style="float:left; padding-right:40px;"><label for="user_email<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>"><?php _e( 'E-mail:', 'theme-my-login' ) ?></label></p>
                <p></p><input type="text" name="user_email" id="user_email<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" class="input" value="<?php $template->the_posted_value( 'user_email' ); ?>" size="20" /></p>



                <p style="float:left; padding-right:10px;"><label for="user_tel<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>"><?php _e( 'Telephone:', 'theme-my-login' ) ?></label></p>
                <p></p><input type="text" name="user_tel" id="user_tel<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" class="input" value="<?php $template->the_posted_value( 'user_tel' ); ?>" size="20" /></p>


                <p style="float:left; padding-right:35px;"><label for="user_mobile<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>"><?php _e( 'Mobile:', 'theme-my-login' ) ?></label></p>
                <p></p><input type="text" name="user_mobile" id="user_mobile<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" class="input" value="<?php $template->the_posted_value( 'user_mobile' ); ?>" size="20" /></p>


                <p style="float:left; padding-right:30px;"><label for="user_country<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>"><?php _e( 'Country:', 'theme-my-login' ) ?></label></p>
                <p></p><input type="text" name="user_country" id="user_country<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" class="input" value="<?php $template->the_posted_value( 'user_country' ); ?>" size="20" /></p>


                <p style="float:left; padding-right:15px;"><label for="user_login<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>"><?php _e( 'Username:', 'theme-my-login' ) ?></label></p>
                <p></p><input type="text" name="user_login" id="user_login<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" class="input" value="<?php $template->the_posted_value( 'username' ); ?>" size="20" /></p>





<?php
do_action( 'register_form' ); // Wordpress hook
do_action_ref_array( 'tml_register_form', array( &$template ) ); //TML hook
?>
        <p id="reg_passmail<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>"><?php echo apply_filters( 'tml_register_passmail_template_message', __( 'A password will be e-mailed to you.', 'theme-my-login' ) ); ?></p>
        <p class="submit">
            <input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" value="<?php _e( 'Register', 'theme-my-login' ); ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php $template->the_redirect_url( 'register' ); ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="instance" value="<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" />
        </p>


    </form>
    <?php $template->the_action_links( array( 'register' => false ) ); ?>
</div>
```

I can see that this is really a basic question but I have been trying for hours and keep coming up with all manner or crazy.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Please...?

I have updated to the following code but is still not working:

```
<?php
/*
If you would like to edit this file, copy it to your current theme's directory and edit it there.
Theme My Login will always look in your theme's directory first, before using this default template.
*/
?>
<div class="login" id="theme-my-login<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>">
    <?php $template->the_action_template_message( 'register' ); ?>
    <?php $template->the_errors(); ?>
    <form name="registerform" id="registerform<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" action="<?php $template->the_action_url( 'register' ); ?>" method="post">

<div id="regwrap">
    <div id="regleft_col">
        <p><label for="user_firstname<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>"><?php _e( 'First Name:', 'theme-my-login' ) ?></label></p>

    </div>
    <div id="regright_col">
        <p></p><input type="text" name="user_firstname" id="user_firstname<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" class="input" value="<?php $template->the_posted_value( 'user_firstname' ); ?>" size="20" /></p>
    </div>
</div>




<?php
do_action( 'register_form' ); // Wordpress hook
do_action_ref_array( 'tml_register_form', array( &$template ) ); //TML hook
?>
        <p id="reg_passmail<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>"><?php echo apply_filters( 'tml_register_passmail_template_message', __( 'A password will be e-mailed to you.', 'theme-my-login' ) ); ?></p>
        <p class="submit">
            <input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" value="<?php _e( 'Register', 'theme-my-login' ); ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php $template->the_redirect_url( 'register' ); ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="instance" value="<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" />
        </p>


    </form>
    <?php $template->the_action_links( array( 'register' => false ) ); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSS code you posted look ok, you just need to insert the <style> tag on the <head> of the page or into the *style.css* file, and then the #wrap inside the form.
Then just put the <p> tags on the column you wish them to be.

By the way, I assume you're getting *tableless* stuff.

Comment: Corner, thanks for the reply. As a newbie I don't quite understand what you mean could you expand a bit further.

Comment: should i put the top code in my style sheet and then replace <p style="float:left; with <p style="left_col";

Comment: Yup, the top code goes into your stylesheet.
You don't need to replace the <p> tags, just throw them inside the "left_col" or "right_col" divs

Comment: H thanks for the help i think im almost there i have tried to following code but it still getting messed up am i missing something simple: